# How do I show only those node that have images available via a view?

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type with image, title, and body fields. I created a view to show these things on front end.
Here images are not available for all nodes of this content type.

I need to show only those nodes in front end that have images.

Comment: @Kiamlaluno why you put this question on hold????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by following steps.

1. Add  **Image** field filter criteria.
2. Now in configuration, select operator **Is not empty (NOT NULL)**.

[image]

Comment: I think the previous comment is obsolete now ...